# MongoDB string index that is not text?

Tags: mongodb, twitter, pymongo

How does MongoDB index a string that is not identified as text?  For example, tweets have many fields that are text, and I create an index for any of them.  In my application, I have created an index for when the tweet was written, who wrote it, and the text of the tweet, but only the text is identified as a text index.

```
import pymongo as pm
db.collection.create_index('created_at')  # tweet creation time is a string
db.collection.create_index('user.screen_name')  # user's screen name
db.collection.create_index([('text', pm.TEXT)])  # tweet text is a string
```

Yet as I can still search the string fields.

```
db.collection.find({'user.screen_name': 'johndoe'})
```

Why?  MongoDB's documentation says only one text index can be created, so what is the difference between an index on a string field and a text index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`text` indexes are for [full-text search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_text_search). Implementation is somewhat more complex than that, but *think* of it as an index on every *word* in the string.

On the contrary, *plain* indexes index the *whole* field at once. They should be your default choice -- even when a field contains a string -- as they are very efficient to search for equality, range or prefix. But not to retrieve a word in the middle of a field.

Given your example, it is quite meaningful to use a plain index on the user name, but to use full-text index on the tweet content.